# R Remove string characters from a range of rows in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `column` in a `dataset` in which I am wanting to remove the first two characters from the rows. Now, the thing is not all rows have these characters, so I don't want to change those rows and some rows are `empty`.

How can I replace the characters in the rows that have them along with removing the rows that are empty and not effect the rows that don't need any modification?

Please note that the original dataset has `305` rows.

Sample Data

```
    Date = c("AA 1/27/2020",
             "BB 1/29/2020",
             "CC 1/30/2020",
             "DD 2/1/2020",
             "2/9/2020",
             "2/15/2020",
             " ",
             " ",
             "EE 2/16/2020",
             "VV 2/17/2020",
             "2/18/2020",
             "2/22/2020",
             "2/25/2020",
             "2/28/2020") 

Date_Approved = c("1/28/2020",
             "1/30/2020",
             "1/31/2020",
             "2/2/2020",
             "2/10/2020",
             "2/16/2020",
             "2/17/2020",
             "2/18/2020",
             "2/17/2020",
             "2/19/2020",
             "2/20/2020",
             "2/23/2020",
             "2/26/2020",
             "2/29/2020")
```

Code

```
    library(tidyverse)
    
   df = data.frame(Date, Date_Approved)

    # Normally I would use
    # Remove Acronyms from date.received column
    df = Date %>% 
             mutate(Date_New= str_sub(Date[], 3, -1))
```

Comment: Do you want `Date1 <- trimws(Date, whitespace = "[A-Z]*\\s*");Date1[nzchar(Date1)]`

Comment: My original `df` has multiple columns so when I do `sep_20_df = df%>% 
         trimws(sub("^[A-Z]+\\s*", "", df$Date))` , I get this error `Error in match.arg(which) : 'arg' must be of length 1`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo so I edited the above comment of mine. So `df` is the original `dataframe` whose `Date` `column` I am trying to modify according to the question and then saving it in `sep_20_df`.

Comment: Your code shows some syntax errors because `Date` is a vector and not a data.frame/tibble

Comment: perhaps`sep_20_df <- df %>% mutate(Date = trimws(Date, whitespace = "[A-Z]*\\s*")) %>% filter(nzchar(Date))`

Comment: @Akrun cheers that worked, if you don't mind an `explanation` for `whitespace` and `nzchar` would also be appreciated for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to substring and filter, an option is to use `trimws` (trims out the characters by default whitespace at either end of the string - if we want only left or right, specify the `which` by default is 'both') with `whitespace` as regex i.e. matching zero or more upper case letters followed by zero or more spaces (`[A-Z]*\\s*`), and then `filter` the rows where the elements are not blank

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Date = trimws(Date, whitespace = "[A-Z]*\\s*")) %>% 
  filter(nzchar(Date))
```

-output

```
       Date Date_Approved
1  1/27/2020     1/28/2020
2  1/29/2020     1/30/2020
3  1/30/2020     1/31/2020
4   2/1/2020      2/2/2020
5   2/9/2020     2/10/2020
6  2/15/2020     2/16/2020
7  2/16/2020     2/17/2020
8  2/17/2020     2/19/2020
9  2/18/2020     2/20/2020
10 2/22/2020     2/23/2020
11 2/25/2020     2/26/2020
12 2/28/2020     2/29/2020
```